# Insert new rows to separate groups of data via a for loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a for loop but I'm open suggestions if there's a better way to separate the data!

I want to insert two new rows whenever the integer in Column 11 or "K" changes. Column K represents groups of data and each is named with integers between 1 and 10 (inclusive). Each group varies in size, hence why I wanted a for loop to check each time the group increments to trigger the insertion of the rows.

For example:
From the data below two blank rows should be inserted below K11 and below K18. This will result in the data being separated by two blank rows whenever two groups were 'touching' each other.

- K2 = 1, K3 = 1, K4 = 1 ... K11 = 1
- K12 = 2, K13 = 2, K14 = 2... K18 = 2
- K19 = 3, K20 = 3 ...

I've put together the following for loop but it inserts 500 (the counter limit) rows after the first group and no row inserts for the remaining groups. Can you explain why this happens and how I can work around this?

```vb
Dim LCounter As Integer
    
For LCounter = 2 To 500
    If Cells(LCounter + 1, 11).Value <> Cells(LCounter, 11) Then
        Rows(LCounter + 1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
    End If   
Next LCounter
```

Comment: If modifying the range you are looping through you need to loop backwards

Comment: After inserting an empty row, the condition for inserting is again `True` and it inserts continuously until the limit of 500. But, do you want inserting two rows or one, after each 'group'? Your description, from this point of view is not so clear.

Comment: Not sure what your final goal is, but this is a simple task in Power Query. And even with VBA, if you data set is large, there may be more efficient methods than looping and inserting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way, please. It should be **very fast** even for big ranges:

```
Sub SeparateGroupsByEmptyRows()
 Dim LCounter As Long, col As Long, rng As Range

 col = 11
 For LCounter = 2 To 500
    If cells(LCounter + 1, col).Value <> cells(LCounter, col).Value Then
       If rng Is Nothing Then
            Set rng = cells(LCounter + 1, col)
       Else
            Set rng = Union(rng, cells(LCounter + 1, col))
       End If
    End If
 Next LCounter
 'For the case of two or more consecutive groups of only one row each:
 If InStr(rng.Address(0, 0), ":") > 0 Then Set rng = makeDiscontinuu(rng)
 rng.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub

Function makeDiscontinuu(rng As Range) As Range
   Dim A As Range, c As Range, strAddress As String
   For Each A In rng.Areas
        If A.cells.count = 1 Then
            strAddress = strAddress & A.Address(0, 0) & ","
        Else
            For Each c In A.cells
                strAddress = strAddress & c.Address(0, 0) & ","
            Next c
        End If
   Next A
   Set makeDiscontinuu = Range(left(strAddress, Len(strAddress) - 1))
End Function
```

Comment: Very creative. A minor inaccuracy: It is inserting a row after the last cell.

Comment: @VBasic2008: Thanks! The 'inaccuracy' would be easy to solve, I knew about it, but I thought that for maximum speed does not matter to insert an empty row after the last empty one. Adding another check (`cell().value <> ""`) will consume some time. Minor amount, it is right, but even if the code looks more complicated than it is, it has been designed to be fast. If the last cell will be calculated, it can also iterate up to the cell before the last. Even now iteration can be done between 2 and 499, but it could look strange for OP...

Answer (score 0):

try this, should be one empty row separation (not tested)

```
Dim LCounter As Integer, lcEnd as integer: lcEnd =500

For LCounter = 2 To lcEnd 
    If Cells(LCounter + 1, 11).Value <> Cells(LCounter, 11) and Cells(LCounter + 1, 11)<> "" Then
        Rows(LCounter + 1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
        lcEnd =lcEnd +1
    End If

Next LCounter
```

Answer (score 0):

### Insert Rows Before Change of Cell Value

- The first procedure uses `For...Next` to solve the problem by looping backwards.
- The second procedure uses `Do...Loop` illustrating the complications when looping forwards.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub insertBeforeChangeForNext()
    
    Const iRows As Long = 2 ' Number of Rows to Insert
    Const cCol As Long = 11 ' Criteria Column
    Const fRow As Long = 2 ' First Row
    ' Either...
    Const lRow As Long = 500 ' Last Row
    ' ...or rather determine the last non-empty row:
    'Dim lRow As Long: lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, cCol).End(xlUp).Row ' LR
    
    If lRow <= fRow Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim LCounter As Long ' Rows Counter
    For LCounter = lRow - 1 To fRow Step -1
        If Cells(LCounter + 1, cCol).Value <> Cells(LCounter, cCol).Value Then
            Rows(LCounter + 1).Resize(iRows).Insert
        End If
    Next LCounter
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub

Sub insertBeforeChangeDoLoop()
    
    Const iRows As Long = 2 ' Number of Rows to Insert
    Const cCol As Long = 11 ' Criteria Column
    Const fRow As Long = 2 ' First Row
    ' Either...
    Const lRow As Long = 500 ' Initial Last Row
    ' ...or rather determine the last non-empty row:
    'Dim lRow As Long: lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, cCol).End(xlUp).Row ' ILR
    
    Dim Current As Long: Current = fRow ' Current Row
    Dim Last As Long: Last = lRow ' Current Last Row
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Do While Current < Last
        If Cells(Current + 1, cCol).Value <> Cells(Current, cCol).Value Then
            Rows(Current + 1).Resize(iRows).Insert
            Last = Last + iRows
            Current = Current + iRows
        End If
        Current = Current + 1
    Loop
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```